# I am trying to upgrade a SR2400SYSD2 server with a more current motherboard

Tags: hardware

Can the Intel SR2400SYSD2 2u be upgraded with a more current motherboard. In other words, is there a 2U motherboard that will fit in the SR2400SYSD2 chassis?

Answer (score 1):

Only with a motherboard that is of the same form factor.  In your case the motherboard appears to be a "SSI Thin E-Bay v1.1".

You might be better off biting the bullet so to speak and upgrade the whole thing to a new server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Intel's documentation](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/chassis/sr2400/sb/sr2400_tps_v20.pdf):

> The Server Chassis SR2400 is mechanically and functionally designed to support the Intel® 
>   Server Board SE7520JR2.and Intel Server Board SE7320VP2.

You're on your own for installing anything else.

As @Matt noted, the motherboard form factor is SSI TEB, so you could theoretically install any  board with that form factor, though you may run into other problems (like baffles not fitting back into place, etc).